# How can I change my default storage engine to MYISAM?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I've run these 2 queries in hopes of setting and retaining the MYISAM storage engine as default:

1.) UPDATE information_schema.ENGINES SET SUPPORT = "DEFAULT" WHERE ENGINE = "MyISAM";

2.) SET SESSION storage_engine = MYISAM;

However, the first query spits out the following error:
Error Code: 1044
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

The second query spits out the following warning:
Warning Code : 1287
'@@storage_engine' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '@@default_storage_engine' instead

which leads me to believe that this snippet is futile in accomplishing this goal.

I've been successful at achieving this once, but for whatever unknown reason, it has reverted back to InnoDB store engine type without my knowing and is being stubborn. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Never done it outside the installation wizard but I'm under the impression that you should add `default-storage-engine=MyISAM` to the server's *.ini file. I'm pretty sure that you aren't supposed to write into `information_schema`. And, of course, if you only change the per-session value is expires with the session.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, that seemed to work. Appreciate your response.